# How do I get parameters out of a Circle?

Tags: snap.svg

Given a circle:

```
var snap = Snap(800,800);
var pl3xx =snap.circle(75, 50, 30);
```

How do I get the parameters back out of it?  I have tried:

```
 var cx = pl3xx.cx;
```

but that does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try attr() to get and set attributes.

```
var cx = pl3xx.attr('cx')
```

[Attr doc](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Element.attr)